# Yoast Seo Plugin - Set no-index to a post automatically when a post is set to sticky

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am a content supervisor on a wordpress site, it uses [wordpress seo by yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin. My duty includes analyzing the content and marking it sticky if seems fit. When I mark a particular post as sticky, there is a function which then sets the post to only appear on the category page. Next thing I have to do is manually set the single-post-view to no-index as instructed by the site-owner.

Since the site is huge, this process is really getting tedious so I am looking for a way to partly automate this process. I am trying to put together a function, which sets the post to no-index, as soon as I update the post as sticky.

First, I would like to know which wp-function is fired when a post is set to sticky. Second, since the site uses [yoast's seo-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/), I would like to know about the seo-plugin's hook/filter which sets the post to no-index. Looking for relevant filters or hooks I found the [seo-plugin API](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/) page of yoast which has a few filters but I could not find anything that could be useful for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my effort to solve this I discovered a [great resource for wordpress hooks](http://hookr.io/) for the job and found the right hook `wpseo_saved_postdata` [here](http://hookr.io/actions/wpseo_saved_postdata/). Feel free to modify the code if you think it could be better. For now, it works for me.

```
function set_noidex_when_sticky($post_id){
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) return;
        //perform other checks

        //if(is_sticky($post_id)){ -----> this may work only AFTER the post is set to sticky
        if (isset($_POST['sticky']) == 'sticky') { //this will work if the post IS BEING SET ticky  
            add_action( 'wpseo_saved_postdata', function() use ( $post_id ) { 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex', '1' );
            }, 999 );
        }
}
 add_action( 'save_post', 'set_noidex_when_sticky' );
```

Only `_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex` was the meta I was targeting to change. Given below are some of yoast's meta keys, if you wanna make any change using the code.

```
_yoast_wpseo_google-plus-description
_yoast_wpseo_linkdex
_yoast_wpseo_opengraph-description
_yoast_wpseo_redirect
_yoast_wpseo_canonical
_yoast_wpseo_sitemap-html-include
_yoast_wpseo_sitemap-prio
_yoast_wpseo_sitemap-include
_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-adv
_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-nofollow
_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex
_yoast_wpseo_metadesc
_yoast_wpseo_title
```

Comment: Should probably use the wpseo_robots filter instead. See [snippet from Yoast dev team](https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/0c71e42aa164238007d7ea88f174a93f#file-yoast_seo_robots_remove_single-php).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the post is sticky and then add noindex? You can use the [Conditional Tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) `is_sticky()`.

So, in your `<head>` tag in your `header.php` file, do the following check:

```
if ( is_sticky() && is_single() ) {
    // it's a post and it's sticky, let's add noindex
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
}
```

Comment: I thought about this way, but wont there be two meta-robots declarations, one through this function and another added by the seo-plugin ?

Comment: Yes it would, then again, we have: http://moz.com/community/q/two-meta-robots-tags-on-a-page-which-will-win Maybe if you can find the function that outputs that declarations, we could hook into it. I think Yoast has hooks...